# Where to find an Oozie Action's STDOUT, STDERR logs once AWS EMR is terminated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oozie, amazon-emr, hue, oozie-workflow

When an EMR cluster is running, the Oozie STDOUT, STDERR and SYSLOG logs can be checked from Web UI, using the Hue application (*if installed on the EMR clusters*). Once the EMR cluster is terminated, we lose the option of viewing those logs from Hue.

I have read that AWS provides an option to store the logs of Oozie in S3, but where exactly could I find the STDOUT and STDERR logs of particular Oozie actions in a workflow, after the termination of EMR clusters?